# cakephp: abstract classes, factory, return objects

Tags: cakephp

I would need an idea or two how I would do this in cakephp (using latest version)

I am building a web based game where you will be able to collect Items

Without a framework I would have an abstract base item class that every item would extend to

And when displaying for example a inventory i would factory all items the user currently have and then return a object for each item.

classes...

```
BaseItem
    WeaponItem
    HealingItem

    etc..
```

How would I do this in cakephp? Would I go for a model for each item class ... and how would i factor to get the object? ...

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a database as the data store, presumably you will use a single table for all items the player can collect? If so, you probably want a single Model class.

It's possible to have an inheritance hierarchy for models in CakePHP if you want. But you can often achieve sharing of Model logic using a Behaviour.